# Geom_qq() Logarithmic Transformation

Tags: r

I am trying to compare some data on a Q-Q plot with the regular distribution of the data and then a distribution with a log transformation of the same variable.

However, I am getting the same plot (though the y-axis has a different range, of course). The x-axis is the same in both plots.

Here is the code for the regular plot:

```
sbpqq <- wcgs %>% 
  ggplot() + geom_qq(mapping = aes(sample = sbp))
sbpqq
```

And here is the code for the log plot:

```
sbpqq <- wcgs %>% 
  ggplot() + geom_qq(mapping = aes(sample = log(sbp)))
sbpqq
```

The two plots, like I said, look the same, although I imagine they should look different (the log transformation on a histogram made the data follow a more normal distribution). Should the plots look the same and I'm just misinterpreting this?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Here are the plots:

**Normal Plot:**

[image: Normal Plot]

**Log Plot:**

[image: Log Plot]

Answer (score 1):

After viewing the two plots side-by-side in RStudio, I realized that they are not identical and that the log plot is more normal than the regular plot.